# Smoothing matlab plot figures

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have obtained the following figure using a 120x120 matrix and the `surf` function.

[image]

Is there a simple way to make the lines between different colors look smoother?

Comment: Zooming out could do the trick. (Perhaps preceded by using a higher initial resolution)

Comment: How did you calculate the lines?

Comment: @Dan: This is the result of an optimization problem, and the resulting matrix is piecewise constant on the hexagons. The lines are made by the `surf` function, not by me. But I guess that the only option is to tune the image myself, or use another software to manage the data.

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin: Higher initial resolution means higher computational costs for my program. I would like that, but the algorithm which gives this is not that fast. And I cannot zoom out, since this is the complete image.

Comment: What if you increase the resolution after calculating the image using nearest neighbour interpolation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, `surf` may not be the best way to display 2D-image - if you don't actually need the height information, `imagesc` will work just fine. Even better, it won't show the differently colored lines between hexagons, since it's not going through the colormap at intersections.

However, regardless of your approach, a low-resolution bitmap will not be automatically transformed into a "arbitrary"-resolution vector graphics - and you may not want that, anyway, if you use the figure to allow you to inspect at which combination of `(x,y)` you obtained at a given value.

There are three approaches to make your image prettier - (1) segment the hexagons, and use `patch` to create a vector-graphics image. (2) upsample the image with `imresample`. (3) create a RGB image and smoothen each color separately to get softer transitions:

```
%# assume img is your image
nColors = length(unique(img));
%# transform the image to rgb
rgb = ind2rgb((img+fliplr(img)),jet(nColors)); %# there are much better colormaps than jet
%# filter each color
for i=1:3,rgbf(:,:,i)=imfilter(rgb(:,:,i),fspecial('gaussian',9,3),'replicate');end
```